# Android Studio with AppEngine - Gradle dependencies

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying the simplest example with Android Studio to create my own backend with [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints) tutorial.

Backend is built and it seems like it's creating the client libraries as well.

The server starts and I can access it from localhost:8080

When I try to build my android app now, the app cannot find following classes

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;
```

neither the client model (called Registration, as in the sample).

How do I have to setup the dependencies of the project in gradle, so that the project can find the correctly generated client libraries?

Currently:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'de.unicate.cloudchat'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Shouldn't that happen automatically in Android Studio?

Comment: Have you found the required dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem. I added the dependencies from this [*Stack Overflow Answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956972/android-studio-2-2-and-gradle-package-does-not-exist).

Add these dependencies:

```
compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
compile ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.17.0-rc') { 
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

See [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/build.gradle?repo=samples)

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of the wizards adds the dependencies to your project automatically(as you mention), what version of android studio are you using?

The modified build.gradle file will have the extra dependency

```
compile project(path: ':<backend-module-name>', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

Comment: Just switched to 0.8.1. I have to try that again.